# Send flag to websocket server

Tags: javascript, php, html, websocket

**Problem short (theoretical) :** is it possible to send a flag from one `php` script to running `php` script that is used as websocket server to notice about database change?

**Problem long (theoretical) :** The current app is using websocket already - when user sends a new data (lets assume - *message*) in `client.html` it is sent to server `server.php`, aggregated and written back to the socket. Now the problem occurs: another users sends in data to `json.php` that does processing and `insert|update` database table. After that has been done the `json.php` should warn `server.php` about the DB change and `server.php` should send (socket write) to `client.html`.

Similar issues here (code almost identitcal to [1.item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960064/php-request-to-php-websocket))

1. [PHP request to PHP Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960064/php-request-to-php-websocket)
2. [Which is more efficient to send WebSocket updates with a MySQL database change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19725491/which-is-more-efficient-to-send-websocket-updates-with-a-mysql-database-change)
3. [Push notifications in PHP using Amazon SNS/SQS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524057/push-notifications-in-php-using-amazon-sns-sqs/11552006#11552006)